# Can't Inject Angular Controller in Mock Test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js

I can't inject my controller in the Mocha test file, it keeps showing this error:

[image: error here]

I followed [the documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing) and tried other approaches, here is the code in test file:

```
var assert = chai.assert;
var expect = chai.expect;
var should = chai.should();

describe('Suplements Module', function(){
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('atari-app'));
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('TestController', {
            '$scope': scope
        });
    }));

    describe('List supplements',function(){
        it('should list all supplements', function(){ });
    });
});
```

Here is my app and controller:

```
angular
    .module('atari-app', [
      'ui.router',
      'ui.utils',
      'oc.lazyLoad',
      'ngResource',
      'ngSanitize',
      'ui.bootstrap',
      'ui.select',
      'authentication-app',
      'angular-ladda',
      'ngAnimate',
      'toastr'
    ]);

  angular.module('atari-app')
    .controller('TestController', ['$scope',
      function ($scope) {
        $scope.testudo = 1;
      }
    ]);
```

My mocha version is 2.5.3 and angular is 1.4.6

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: @Graham no :/ sorry

Comment: I figured it out eventually. In my case it was because I wasn't creating a mock for several of the dependencies being injected into the controller by angular. Once I created those mocks for the injected dependencies then it worked.

Comment: I will try this now. if it works, could you put it as an answer? tks